# Create an infographics to navigate an en online ebook

Tags: html, navigation, css-animations

I'm thinking about a graphic solution to navigate an ebook on line: a circle or another animation divided into pieces like a pie chart. A circle animated and cliccable like this: http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/

When I click on a piece, the corresponding chapter will be opened.

- Did you know if on the web someone have created ebook navigation like this?
- I'm thinking to use a js library to create animations and then unserstand how to insert chapter. Use a simple pdf and create static link or insert chapters on a db or xml or json file?

Comment: Hi Gabriele and welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to read the ["how to ask" FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) so your questions won't get closed.

Comment: Hi, excuse me but i don't see what is wrong in my question. i described what i'd like to do and then i post two questions. Please help me to understand. Thanks

Comment: Hi Gabriele, please see the ["What topics can I ask about here"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) help pages.

Comment: Hi vzwick, i tried to edit my question with your suggestions!